How long is it safe to wait for my well pump to gains enough pressure?
I just need to know like how long would it be safe to wait before I should go turn it off as I don't want it to be damaged and I also know that it does need to gain pressure.  I opened the valve to let some air out I do have a big air tank it's like 60 gallons it's a centrifugal wellpump.

There's not nearly enough information here.

If the pressure gauge isn't moving within a minute, turn it off and fix the priming (if it's a jet pump) or pull the pump (if it's a submersible and you have verified that power is being supplied to it.) If you're not experienced with pulling a pump, you may choose to call a well/pump service for that part.
If the pressure gauge moves, but stops increasing before it gets to shutoff, again, shut it down if it sits and spins for a minute without increasing. That may indicate a problem with the pump other than having lost prime, or a problem with the water level in the well.
